# Search(Firefox-Ubuntu) made on the navigation bar always have "canonical&ia=web"

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-16.04

When i focus on navigation bar using "CTR + L" to search(i use duckduckgo as default on firefox) always the result has "canonical&ia=web" at the end of www direction: What does it mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What does it mean?

> `t=canonical` is a partner tag that allows Ubuntu to generate revenue from searches on DuckDuckGo that use Ubuntu (anonymously)

Source [DuckDuckGo on Twitter](https://twitter.com/duckduckgo/status/369587275056705536)

> `&t=`
>
> Through partnerships with developers and companies, DuckDuckGo has
>   been integrated into many applications. In these partnerships, a
>   portion of DuckDuckGo's advertising revenue is sometimes shared back.
>   To assign advertising revenue and collect anonymous aggregate usage
>   information, developers add a unique "&t=" parameter to searches made
>   through their applications.

Source [&t=](https://duck.co/help/privacy/t)

`&ia=web` - the `ia` is short for "instant access" but I can't find a good web reference that describes this parameter.

Comment: Thank you David.

It's means they know what i'm searching?

Comment: @HaroldoPayaresSalgado Yes, but it's anonymous data.

Comment: @HaroldoPayaresSalgado Technically ANY search engine "knows" what request it received, it wouldn't work either way. However Google uses this information in any possible way, whereas DDG is supposed to only use this info to return the corresponding results, without profiling the user.